# Magento Export/Import Problems

Tags: magento

Can anyone tell me which server configuration will be required for a Magento site with 50k customers and more than 2k products?

I've been experiencing a lot of speed-related issues and 500 Internal Server Errors while attempting to export customers.

I also have other issues such as: no visible Reorder button on cancelled orders;
when exporting products and customers the Continue button is not visible; and other issues. I am using Plesk panel.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depends what you mean by 50K customers. The requirements for it running smoothly will depend on the number of hits per second/minute you have. The 500 internal server error on exporting customers could be down to it hitting a memory limit, when playing with large collections I've had Magento use upwards of 1Gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to look at the Amazon servers or Stackable hosting services.

Depending on your traffic per day, and not so much on the amount of customers or products, I can give you more info.

Have you installed lightspeed caching for caching some of the big pages?

This can help allot, if you have a server available with at least 4GB ram, and will also take some load off from the processing power needed to render non-cached pages.

http://www.tinybrick.com/improve-magentos-slow-performance.html

Have a look at http://www.skullcandy.com and http://www.astrogaming.com for speed samples.
They have allot of products, and allot of visits, and some realy cool headsets! :)